# Google Place Search does not return result

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I need to fetch location data based on given text.
As example if I search `Aldi` in google map it shows me lot of data with pagination. I need to get that result using google places api.

I tried it with two API calls. But it returns me following result

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Aldi&key=MY_KEY

Result

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=ALDI&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,name,formatted_address,geometry&key=MY_KEY

Result

```
{
   "candidates" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I need to fetch data based on the given name. Can anyone find out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that Places API search is not designed to provide results world wide. In your examples you specify only text value 'Aldi'. However, in order to get results you should specify also where you are searching.

For example, if I want to bias results towards Barcelona area in Spain I have to add location and radius in my request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Aldi&location=41.3850639%2C2.1734035&radius=10000&key=MY_API_KEY`

This request will return Aldi supermarkets in Barcelona area as shown in my screenshot

[image]

The same thing for Find place, you should specify location bias

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Aldi&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry,name,place_id&locationbias=circle%3A1000%4041.3850639%2C2.1734035&key=MY_API_KEY`

Also note that Find place returns only one result.

I hope this addresses your doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about having paginated data based on search key. According to your answer I must use `textsearch`. But I need result from world wide. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Places API search is working only for specified area. If you need results world wide you should do multiple requests for different areas, also note that Places API can return up to 60 results for one area, so there is no guarantee that you get all possible results. This API returns only prominent items according to Google criteria.

Comment: @xomena, could you please tell me how to get location and radius fields to be specified as you did in your example?

Answer (score 5):

There are three types of searches provided by the Places API: [Find Place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests), [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) and [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests). Each allows you to specify a location with radius to start the search from. The location is specified as a latitude/longitude pair. You received ZERO_RESULTS because you didn't specify a location for your request. If the location parameter is not specified "the API uses IP address biasing by default" according to the documentation. So, there are no Aldi stores within range of the location of your IP address.

**Find Place** will only return one result though, in my experience, it sometimes returns two. Both **Nearby Search** and **Text Search** will return up to 60 place results. All three of the Place search requests allow specifying a radius around your location of up to 50 kilometers. If you need to find Aldi places worldwide you'll need to make quite a few requests.

I am weeks into a similar project to find all locations for a list of restaurant chains in the US. I have found that Nearby Search is a better choice for my use case and should be considered always before committing to Text Search for a project. I've tested Aldi searches with both Nearby Search and Text Search and found that **they provide the identical set of place_id results**. This Nearby Search request will find all Aldi locations within 50 kilometers of New York City:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.785276%2C-73.9651827&name=Aldi&radius=50000&key=MY_API_KEY
```

Here is the same as a Text Search:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Aldi&location=40.785276%2C-73.9651827&radius=50000&key=MY_API_KEY
```

So why should we care? Text Search according to API documentation "...  returns all of the available data fields for the selected place, and you will be billed accordingly." Furthermore "... the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota." A Nearby Search request is less expensive and not subject to the 10x multiplier. It returns a subset of the available data fields that you might find sufficient. If you need additional data fields, you can get only what you need from a Places Detail request. Do the math for your application before you select Text Search. It might be dramatically less expensive to implement using Nearby Search followed by Places Detail requests if necessary. In any case, you don't want to be shocked when you hit quota limits unexpectedly because of the 10x multiplier OR the billed transaction costs are more than you expect!

I have found additional hurdles that should be considerations for projects attempting to find all locations for a business in a large area:

1. The Places API will prefer places within your radius but will include places outside your radius if it determines they are relevant and within the 60 place limit. I have had places returned more than 450 kilometers from my requested search position.
2. Results are going to be returned for places with names that are NOT what you searched for. In my search for the restaurant Benihana in Seattle a Nearby Search request only returns a restaurant with the name Hamansu. Upon investigation, this is because there is not a Benihana in Seattle, however, Hamansu is similar to Benihana in that it serves Japanese dishes grilled tableside. The API documentation states your search term will be "matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content."
3. Results are returned 20 at a time. If there are more results, a page_token is provided to make a request to get the next page of up to 20 results. Each request is chargeable. You will be billed for the 3 requests required to get 60 results. I'm not saying this is bad, just be aware of the expense and quota usage you are incurring with this API.
4. If there are more than 60 results for your radius then you haven't found all the possible locations within it. And, you can't determine with certainty what the effective radius covered was for the 60 results. You need to search with a small enough radius to return < 60 results for each request. A worldwide search is going to require a large quota and $ budget to pursue.

Comment: Client requirement was to find all places related to given country. That's why I had to choose text search. To do it I had to fetch all the cities on the country and do search according search results of city search. Thank you for your detailed explanation. Hope it will help to someone.

Comment: How did you build the list of cities to search? My problem is I have the same project for US where there are approximately 1,000 cities where locations "might" be. Also, I still don't have a feasible solution for a search that returns more than 60 results. Quota limits and cost become an issue if I reduce the radius and do multiple searches for each city. Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Firstly found cities from google api. Then after iterate text search based on city search and could get more than 600 plashes based on single search. Number of results may change based on search country. If you need more info i can help you. Drop a mail to e06widu@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

@Art answer, which is marked with higher upvotes, is only partially correct. The answer suggests that the Find Place api (e.g. maps/api/place/findplacefromtext) will usually return 1 result, at most 2. I tend to agree with him. Even if your search hits multiple targets, only one would be returned with the Find Place api. Consequently, he recommends to use Nearby Search or Text Search, both of which would yield at most 60 results.

However, these two searches require some form of location parameter, otherwise they will likely return 0 results, defaulting to using your IP address, as he indicates. But he recommends using a location accompanied with a radius parameter. The problem with this is the radius parameter has a maximum limit. So it will not target all types of things you want if you are searching over the stretch of an entire country, such as the United States.

The truth is you do not need to use the location and radius. There is another option called region. And you can use region to search the entire distance of a country.

What @Art suggested:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=25.7392%2C-80.3103&name=Law%Offices%of%Alex&radius=50000&key=KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Law%Offices%of%Alex&location=25.7392%2C-80.3103&radius=50000&key=KEY

A more encompassing alternative:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Law%Offices%of%Alex&region=us&key=KEY

Comment: `region` is not supported by `findplacefromtext`. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of your search.